# Python: How to compare large one-dimesional arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, compare

I am Python Newbie and search for the fastest Python solution for this request:

Requirements:

- Two one-dimensional lists "listA" and "listB"
- It does NOT matter whether the lists are np.arrays or not (speed matters!)
- Lists have exact same size
- Each list contains around 7,000,000 int8 values
- The lists should be compared
- A new list ("ret" called) should be returned
- "ret" should
  a) contain the value "listB[i]"
  b) at position [i]
  c) in case "abs( listA[i] - listB[i] ) > noise"

```
def Delta(list_a: np.array, list_b: np.array, noise: int) -> np.array:
    len_a_and_b = len(list_a)
    ret = np.zeros(shape=(len_a_and_b))
    for i in range(len_a_and_b):
        if abs(list_a[i] - list_b[i]) > noise:
            ret[i] = list_b[i]
    return ret
```

The code above works but is very slow.
I am sure that some "magic" np function will do the job in milliseconds.
Any hint would be great.
Thxs in advance.

EDIT:

```
list_a = np.array([100, 200, 255, 100, 204, 205])
list_b = np.array([100, 201, 240, 120, 200, 200])
ret = Delta(list_a, list_b, noise=4)
print(ret) # -> [0, 0, 240, 120, 0, 200]
```

Comment: thats very easy with numpy are u sure ure allowed to use it?

Comment: Please [edit] to show sample input and output data, as your description of your expected output is unclear. For example, what should be at position `[i]` if the abs val of the difference is NOT > `noise`?

Comment: Yes, you should replace your for/if with the equivalent in NumPy broadcast operations.  Where are you stuck with that?  What aren't you getting from the tutorials on NumPy?

Comment: @G.Anderson: Mmh. I believe its clear: a)two one dimension arrays, b) each contains around 7,000,000 int8 values c) ret = np.zeros(...).

Comment: @Prune: Thx 4 your very fast answer. numpy lib is soooo big ... as said I am Newbie and doesnt get a "handle" on this extremly large numpy lib.But 4 sure I will deep dive in the docs. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = np.random.randint(0,100,size=1000000)
B = np.random.randint(0,100,size=1000000)
C = np.where(np.abs(A-B)>20,B,np.nan)
print(C)
```

`np.where` will check where the `abs(A-B)>noise=20` and will give the `B` value for those cases. Otherwise, `else` it gives `np.nan` something like a `null value`. You can change it as you please, but in general this should sum up your exercise.

Comment: WOW! Thanks! That´s it. I just have to replace "np.nan" with 0. Works great!